# To much logic inside list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list comprehension in my code that looks something like this :

```
dataPointList = [
     map(str, 
        [ elem for elem in dataFrame[column] 
           if not pd.isnull(elem) and '=' in elem
        ]
     ) for column in list(dataFrame)
]
```

I was wondering, is there a general rule of thumb when to break up a list comprehension? Can you have too much logic inside a list comprehension?

Comment: Afaik, there is no such rule of thumb. That being said, you can simplify this expression.

Comment: A good time to break a comprehension, is maybe when it becomes hard to read; in your example, it is easy to read and understand at a glance.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to mix `map` and list comprehensions, especially when map isn't needed at all:

```
>>> list(map(str, [x for x in [1, 2, 3]]))
['1', '2', '3']
>>> [str(x) for x in [1, 2, 3]]
['1', '2', '3']
```

It means you can simply apply `str[elem]` directly in your list comprehension:

```
dataPointList = [
    [ str(elem) for elem in dataFrame[column]
       if not pd.isnull(elem) and '=' in elem
    ] for column in list(dataFrame)
]
```

Then, a `DataFrame` is already iterable. There's no need to convert it to a list:

```
>>> [x for x in list(pd.DataFrame(d))]
['one', 'two']
>>> [x for x in pd.DataFrame(d)]
['one', 'two']
```

Your code becomes :

```
dataPointList = [
    [ str(elem) for elem in dataFrame[column]
       if not pd.isnull(elem) and '=' in elem
    ] for column in dataFrame
]
```

Note that since you want a nested list, you cannot use a double list comprehension:

```
>>> [(a,b) for a in x for b in y]
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
>>> [[(a,b) for b in y] for a in x]
[[(1, 3), (1, 4)], [(2, 3), (2, 4)]]
```